# How to get two digit number behind dot/. (C)

Tags: c

I'm completly new at codding things, and I started at C, so I've question how to get one/two digit number behing the dot(.) for price, i'm kinda confused while using %-30lf.

```
void displayItems(){
system("cls");
printf("Display Items!\n\n");
printf("%-10s %-20s %-20s %-20s %s\n", "ID", "Name Item", "Price", "Quantity", "Date");
printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

fp = fopen("items.txt", "rb");
while(fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, fp)== 1){
    printf("%-10d %-20s %-20lf %-20d %s\n", p.id, p.namaItem, p.price, p.quantity, p.date);
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

```
*/ The Output
ID         Name Item            Price                Quantity             Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          aa                   20.000000            1                    17/03/2023
*/
```

I've tried using %0.2 and else, but I'm kinda stuck and confused, thank you!

Comment: What about `%-20.2f`?

Comment: In the first place, it's usually better to used fixed-point representation and arithmetic for currency -- for example, an integral number of cents rather than a floating-point number of dollars.

Comment: But if you do use floating point, then the number of decimal places to print can be controlled via the precision field in the conversion specifier.  For example, the `.2` in `%-20.2f`.

Comment: Other than with `scanf` you don't need `%lf` for `double` with `printf`. You can use `%f` instead. `float` arguments are promoted to `double` automatically for variadic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about %-20.2f? – Gerhardh

> In the first place, it's usually better to used fixed-point representation and arithmetic for currency -- for example, an integral number of cents rather than a floating-point number of dollars. – John Bollinger

> But if you do use floating point, then the number of decimal places to print can be controlled via the precision field in the conversion specifier. For example, the .2 in %-20.2f. – John Bollinger

> Other than with scanf you don't need %lf for double with printf. You can use %f instead. float arguments are promoted to double automatically for variadic functions. – Gerhardh

**Thank you so much, you guys solved my problem, thank you for the suggestion and correction!**